# Is it possible to retrieve False Positives/ False Negatives identified by a confusion Matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning

I am using Sckit-learn and am using a Confusion Matrix to get more insight into how my algorithm is performing:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(keywords_list, 

label_list, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

pipeline.fit(X_train, Y_train)

pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)

print(confusion_matrix(Y_test, pred))
```

I am getting an output like this:

```
[[1011   72]
[ 154 1380]]
```

Which I assume follows the format for these Matrixes:

```
TP|FP
FN|TN
```

Is it possible to retrieve the values that are being classified as false positives and False Negatives? Knowing what that data looks like would be helpful towards my work. it goes without saying I am new to Sckit-Learn.

EDIT:

Alessandro gave good advice by informing me that `Y_test != pred` would return all of my false positives/negatives in the confusion matrix.

One factor that I should have mentioned in my original question is that I am classifying textual data under binary labels. (E.g. Ham/Spam) and I want to identify them seperately from each other. My current code for extracting false negatives is taking the form of:

```
false_neg = open('false_neg.csv', 'w')
falsen_list = X_test[(Y_test == 'Spam') and (pred == 'Ham')] #False Negatives
wr2 = csv.writer(false_neg, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for x in falsen_list:
    wr2.writerow([x])
```

Unfortunately, this throws an error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noname365/PycharmProjects/MLCorpusBlacklist/CorpusML_training.py", line 171, in <module>
    falsen_list = X_test[(Y_test == 'blacklisted') and (pred == 'clean')] #False Negatives
  File "/home/noname365/virtualenvs/env35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 731, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 1):

`Y_test != pred` gives you the answers you predicted incorrectly
Partciularly `(Y_test == 1) == (pred == 0)` should give you the false positives and `(Y_test == 0) == (pred == 1)` should give you the false negatives (or it could be the other way around depending on what is positive and negative in your setup)

Comment: This works, But one thing I forgot to mention is that I am working with text data in my algorithm. As such, I get the token occurrences of all words returned. How would I match the occurrence to the word effectively?

Comment: Depending on the size of your data you could do something like: X_test[Y_test != pred] and that would show your the occurencies in the data.

Comment: Thanks but applying that code to specifically target False positives or False negatives 'X_test[(Y_test == 1) == (pred == 0)]' returns the same number of elements for both. 221, so the false positives and negatives are being merged into one list.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

Adding '&' at the place of '==' in Alessandro's answer (his answer gave both false positives and false negatives together)

```
(Y_test == 1) & (pred == 0)
```